# New badge notification doesn't go away when viewing profile using username link

Tags: feature-request, notifications

The message bar when I get a new badge reads "You've earned the *whatever* badge. See your profile." If I view my profile using the "profile" link, the notification bar goes away. But if I view my profile in another way (by clicking on my username for example) the notification does not go away. Seems like both should get rid of the notification.

Answer (score 2):

A ***single*** notification bar would be nice. I have had at least 2 show up, then I'm forced to go deal with it as I lose my screen real-estate - by an overtly orange bar nonetheless. *I* don't mind the notifications, actually I like them.

However, it would be nice if there were some options:

1. preference to dismiss notification bars based on an interval
2. opt to not have them shown
3. make the reward notification bar a bit smaller
4. combine multiple awards into one notification

Comment: This is what I talked about: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39095/
These orange bars are very annoying! I have received so many today!

Comment: @Tony maybe you shouldn't be such an overachiever!

Comment: @Tony: your example inspired me to be creative with some suggestions. If they get noticed, improved, and ok'd, then your voice has been heard and the community is better for it. ;)

Comment: Thank you. You are a rare polite voice today!

Comment: So...why did this answer get down-voted? A polite comment can get the concern rectified pretty quickly.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

I *like* that the notifications are "sticky." I might have other reasons to peek at my profile without digging into the reason for the notification.

The notification is **a good "sticky note"** to remind me to check something specific. When I am done with it, I can click on the profile link or the "X" to dismiss it. I wouldn't want it **inadvertently dismissed as a side effect** of something else I did.

I vote to leave it the way it is.