# Dismiss the notification bar when I click any link contained within it

Tags: feature-request, notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Notification bar doesn't disappear on clicking the question.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58473/notification-bar-doesnt-disappear-on-clicking-the-question)

If I'm notified that one of my questions has earned me some badge or other, and I click the link to see that question (or the one for my profile), it should have the same effect as clicking the `[X]` link - I don't need to see the notification pop up again when I get to the new page.

In fact, perhaps the bar could only be shown once, and automatically dismissed when I next click on **any** link on the page.

It's pretty hard to miss, I think you can assume I have seen it if I have performed any action on the page, and especially if I clicked a link inside it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Notification bar doesn't disappear on clicking the question.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58473/notification-bar-doesnt-disappear-on-clicking-the-question) Also see: [New badge notification doesn't go away when viewing profile using username link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34375/new-badge-notification-doesnt-go-away-when-viewing-profile-using-username-link)

Comment: Ah, damnit - I searched before asking, I swear

Comment: If it's any consolation, this has bothered me for a long time. My search was just more successful, albeit more disappointing finding that `status-bydesign`. :-)